# What is the exact meaning of "sth gives way on"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm reading an article and i'm not sure what this means. "The steep cliffs **give way on** the eastern side where there seems to be a lawn beside the sea"

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Perhaps the writer meant *make way*.

Comment: The parsing is more likely *(give way) (on the eastern side)*, rather than *give way on* as a single phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It’s simply a poetic way of saying that there is a lawn below the cliffs to the East and beyond the lawn is the sea. “Give way,” in this context basically means to yield. In other words, the cliffs yield to the lawn and the sea.

Comment: Note that, literally speaking, "give way" means to collapse (as a bridge) or to allow through (as a guard at a gate).  The quoted usage is saying the cliffs figuratively "collapse" down to the lawn.